After restoring etcd data and modifying node labels, there is a situation where pods cannot be scheduled under statefulset
My test environment is two control panel nodes(Suppose they are A and B respectively, and that at the beginning A has the pod's nodeselector tag cur=true.), and one etcd node (using binary files to install etcd).
Now I'm restoring the latest data from the etcd backup.
systemctl stop etcd
# /data/paas/etcd is the data directory for etcd
rm -rf /data/paas/etcd/*
latest_backup=$(ls -t /data/paas/bak/etcd/*db | head -n 1)
etcdutl snapshot restore $latest_backup --data-dir /data/paas/etcd
systemctl start etcd

Next, I removed the original cur=true label from A and added the cur=true label to B.
kubectl label node A cur-
kubectl label node B cur=true

Next, I manually deleted the pod to trigger the rescheduling so that the pod would schedule on the node that matched its nodeselector.
But there seems to be a problem with loki scheduling.
Name:             loki-0
Namespace:        loki
Priority:         0
Service Account:  loki
Node:             <none>
Labels:           app=loki
                  controller-revision-hash=loki-f7c6fcc5b
                  log=
                  name=loki
                  release=loki
                  statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=loki-0
Annotations:      checksum/config: e0e66b24e1875db598d3ff702f02820e7f074ac8546d32c4e26e2d759562a4eb
                  prometheus.io/port: http-metrics
                  prometheus.io/scrape: true
Status:           Pending
IP:
IPs:              <none>
Controlled By:    StatefulSet/loki
Containers:
  loki:
    Image:       192.168.44.100:1080/system_containers/loki:2.6.1
    Ports:       3100/TCP, 9095/TCP, 7946/TCP
    Host Ports:  0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    Args:
      -config.file=/etc/loki/loki.yaml
    Liveness:     http-get http://:http-metrics/ready delay=45s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:    http-get http://:http-metrics/ready delay=45s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /data from storage (rw)
      /etc/loki from config (rw)
      /rules from monitor-rules (rw)
      /rules/fake from rules (rw)
      /tmp from tmp (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-4b6gf (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  storage-loki-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  tmp:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  rules:
    Type:      ConfigMap (a volume populated by a ConfigMap)
    Name:      loki-alerting-rules
    Optional:  false
  config:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  loki
    Optional:    false
  monitor-rules:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  kube-api-access-4b6gf:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              cur=true
Tolerations:                 node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane:NoSchedule op=Exists
                             node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                From               Message
  ----     ------            ----               ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  42m                default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod, 1 Preemption is not help
ful for scheduling..
  Warning  FailedScheduling  21m (x4 over 36m)  default-scheduler  0/2 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match Pod's node affinity/selector. preemption: 0/2 nodes are available: 1 No preemption victims found for incoming pod, 1 Preemption is not help
ful for scheduling..

Events tells us that one node (A) does not satisfy affinity/selector, but why doesn't B? I can't tell you why, but the resources on node B are more than enough.
Here are some things that will help troubleshoot the problem:
# kubectl get pod -n loki loki-0 -o wide
NAME     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP       NODE     NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
loki-0   0/1     Pending   0          49m   <none>   <none>   <none>           <none>

# kubectl get node --show-labels
ubectl get node --show-labels
NAME      STATUS      ROLES           AGE   VERSION    LABELS
A          Ready    control-plane   3d13h   v1.27.3   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=A,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane=,node.kubernetes.io/exclude-from-external-load-balancers=
B          Ready    control-plane   3d13h   v1.27.3   beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux,cur=true,kubernetes.io/arch=amd64,kubernetes.io/hostname=B,kubernetes.io/os=linux,node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane=,node.kubernetes.io/exclude-from-external-load-balancers=

# kubectl get statefulset -n loki loki -o yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: loki
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: loki
  creationTimestamp: "2024-05-25T13:49:27Z"
  generation: 1
  labels:
    app: loki
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    chart: loki-2.16.0
    heritage: Helm
    log: ""
    release: loki
  name: loki
  namespace: loki
  resourceVersion: "306423"
  uid: 124b0986-340d-4d3c-ad32-c859a08ac461
spec:
  persistentVolumeClaimRetentionPolicy:
    whenDeleted: Retain
    whenScaled: Retain
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: loki
      release: loki
  serviceName: loki-headless
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: e0e66b24e1875db598d3ff702f02820e7f074ac8546d32c4e26e2d759562a4eb
        prometheus.io/port: http-metrics
        prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: loki
        log: ""
        name: loki
        release: loki
    spec:
      affinity: {}
      containers:
      - args:
        - -config.file=/etc/loki/loki.yaml
        image: 192.168.44.100:1080/system_containers/loki:2.6.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /ready
            port: http-metrics
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 45
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        name: loki
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3100
          name: http-metrics
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9095
          name: grpc
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 7946
          name: memberlist-port
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /ready
            port: http-metrics
            scheme: HTTP
          initialDelaySeconds: 45
          periodSeconds: 10
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 1
        resources: {}
        securityContext:
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
        terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
        terminationMessagePolicy: File
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp
        - mountPath: /rules
          name: monitor-rules
        - mountPath: /etc/loki
          name: config
        - mountPath: /data
          name: storage
        - mountPath: /rules/fake
          name: rules
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      nodeSelector:
        cur: true
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 10001
        runAsGroup: 10001
        runAsNonRoot: true
        runAsUser: 10001
      serviceAccount: loki
      serviceAccountName: loki
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 4800
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane
        operator: Exists
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: tmp
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: loki-alerting-rules
        name: rules
      - name: config
        secret:
          defaultMode: 420
          secretName: loki
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: monitor-rules
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: storage
    spec:
      accessModes:
      - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 10Gi
      storageClassName: openebs-hostpath
      volumeMode: Filesystem
    status:
      phase: Pending
status:
  availableReplicas: 0
  collisionCount: 0
  currentReplicas: 1
  currentRevision: loki-f7c6fcc5b
  observedGeneration: 1
  replicas: 1
  updateRevision: loki-f7c6fcc5b
  updatedReplicas: 1

I tried modifying /etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-scheduler.yaml on node B by adding --v=5, then restarting the kubelet, removing the triggered rescheduling of loki-0's pod, and looking at the logs there doesn't seem to be anything helpful.
version info
Kubernetes v1.27.3
Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc
# 
etcd Version: 3.5.13
Git SHA: c9063a0dc
Go Version: go1.21.8
Go OS/Arch: linux/amd64

I tried switching to the etcd version 3.5.7 bundled with Kubernetes v1.27.3, but I still get the same problem! Also try to recover etcd data with --bump-revision 1350000 --mark-compacted (overwrite snapshot from 20 minutes ago).
If additional information is needed, please ask.
I'm at a loss with this issue, I suspect it's caused by a corruption in the etcd data, any help or ideas would be appreciated!

is this the only deployment that is facing this issue..? I mean do you have any other application pods running on these nodes. If you are not having any, can you try creating a simple hello world deployment and check whether the pods are getting deployed correctly.

I apologize for only replying now. The reason I seem to have found is because pvc has a ReadWriteOnce access mode, and I'm using the storage class “openebs”, which doesn't support local pv's with a ReadWriteMany access mode for the time being, and is unrelated to etcd.
failed to provision volume with StorageClass “openebs-hostpath”: only support ReadWriteOnce access mode. I'm not very good at English, I use a translation program, please forgive me!@KranthiveerDontineni

Only the issue with pods deployed via StatefulSet is problematic, but I'm surprised there's no message when I change the label cur=true.
